# Famo.us: Slideshow tutorial with the Picasa API is out of date

Tags: famo.us

I've been working on the famo.us Slideshow tutorial and realised that the API is no longer working.

Any ideas how can I still make this to work without the Picasa API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the API by using the [following code for SlideData.js](https://github.com/talves/famous-slideshow-webpack/blob/master/src/data/SlideData.js)

You can make it work by creating the objects returned by the url + parameters below and returning them as the JSON object if you do not want to use the API.

```js
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    var SlideData = {
        picasaUrl: 'https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/all',
        queryParams: '?kind=photo&q=puppy&max-results=5&imgmax=720&alt=json',
        defaultImage: 'https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Roszbra0TlI/VB-fE83NAXI/AAAAAAAAACU/ITmhyZMHZrk/s720/cute%252520looking%252520white%252520and%252520black%252520french%252520Bulldog%252520Puppy.jpg'
    };

    SlideData.getUrl = function() {
        return SlideData.picasaUrl + SlideData.queryParams;
    };

    SlideData.parse = function(data) {
        var urls = [];
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        var entries = data.feed.entry;
        for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
            var media = entries[i].media$group;
            urls.push(media.media$content[0].url);
        }
        return urls;
    };

    module.exports = SlideData;
});
```